# É possível alterar o formato dos botões no Owl Carousel?

Tags: owl-carousel

Tenho um slider feito com Owl Carousel mas não encontro um modo de alterar os botões *next* e *prev*. Gostaria de fazer um círculo com as setas dentro.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, você pode incluir um CSS customizado que irá alterar os botões originais do Owl Carousel. Você pode fazer isso criando pseudo-elementos `::before` e `::after` e ajustando os estilos como quiser (dimensões, cores, tamanho da seta etc.).

O CSS abaixo irá alterar os botões conforme os estilos definidos. Irá substituir os botões originais por botões de `50px` com uma seta preta ao meio (vide imagem):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Note que foi usado alguns `!important` para sobrepor algumas
>   definições originais do plugin.

```
<style>
/* ajusto os botões no tamanho que eu quero */
.owl-prev, .owl-next{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
   background: none !important;
}

/* crio os pseudo-elementos */
.owl-prev::before, .owl-next::before{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: red;
   border-radius: 50% !important;
   line-height: 50px;
}

/* hover para mudar de cor */
.owl-prev:hover::before, .owl-next:hover::before{
   background: aqua;
}

/* crio as setas e centralizo */
.owl-prev::after, .owl-next::after {
   content: "";
   width: 18px;
   height: 18px;
   position: absolute;
   transform: rotate(135deg);
   border: solid black;
   border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
   top: 50%; left: 50%;
   margin-top: -9px;
   margin-left: -4px;
}

/* ajusto a seta next */
.owl-next::after {
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
   margin-left: -14px;
}
</style>
```